# Using Imagemagick with a file from a mongo collection

Tags: meteor, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm building a simple database for small pixel-art files. The images are saved directly to the database:

```
Template.pixUpload.events({
    'change .myPixInput': function(event, template) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var file = event.target.files[0]; //assuming 1 file only
        if (!file) return;

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(event){
            MyPix.insert({
                binary: reader.result,
                createdAt: new Date
            });
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
})
```

The idea is to be able to modify the images on their way back to the browser, scale them on the fly (if things don't get too slow). So I'm trying to read the image from the db, and scale it with Imagemagick, before displaying it. It doesn't work – and I can't find anything helpful I would be able to understand:

```
Template.pixList.helpers({
    'thumbnail': function() {
        var bin = this.binary;
        var thumb = new FileReader();
        Imagemagick.convert(['bin', '-filter', 'point', '64x64', 'thumb']);
        return thumb;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

im using `GM Package` Right now, take a look at full repo [here](https://atmospherejs.com/cfs/standard-packages)

**First Install All FSCollecton Packages.**

> GridFS (Because you say you want to store the file inside MongodB).
>
> Graphicsmagick `meteor add cvs:graphicsmagick`

**Second Declare collections on `/lib/collection.js`**

```
  kaiStackExample = new FS.Collection("kaiStackExample ", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.GridFS("kaiStackExample ",{
    beforeWrite:function(fileObj){
      return {
            extension: 'png',
            type: 'image/png'
          };
    },
    transformWrite:function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream){
      // Here you can choose, for example 10x10 (thumbnail), etc.
         gm(readStream).resize(600).stream('PNG').pipe(writeStream);
    }
  })]
});
```

and our basic Subscribe, on the same `/lib/collection.js`

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.subscribe('kaiStackExample');
}
```

> Ok, at this point we have the GridFS and GM, to verify both

```
server console.
=> GraphicsMagick found

Client console.

kaiStackExample.find().fetch();
```

should return `[]`;

**Third SECURITY**

```
kaiStackExample.allow({
insert:function(userId,doc){
//here we can do stuff like, only permit user with accounts insert on the collection
if(!Meteor.userId()){
   return false;
    }else{
   return true
   },
update:function(userId,doc){
   if(userId === doc.authorId{
         return true;
    }else{
        return false; // if user don't own the document can update it.
    }
  }
});
```

**Four Template and Events**

HTML markup

```
<template name="exampleKai">
Select File
<input type="file" id="fileExampleKai">
<button type="submit" id="buttonExampleKai">Click to upload</button>
</template>
```

Js Code

```
Template.exampleKai.events({
  'click #buttonExampleKai':function(event,template){
    event.preventDefault();
    var file = $('#fileExampleKai').get(0).files[0];
        fsFile = new FS.File(file);
    fsFile.metadata = {
        coolMetadata:"Yes You can add some metadata too"
     }
     if(file === undefined){
       alert("Please upload a file to continue")
     }else{
       kaiStackExample.insert(fsFile,function(err,succes){
          if(err){
             console.log(err.reason);
           }else{
             console.log("ok we insert yeaaa")
            }
        });
      }
  }
});
```

Like i say this works for me, and i think its your best option for editing `size,type,etc` Take a look hope it help you

Comment: Wow thanks @Ethaan! Slowly going through this. First question is about the `beforeWrite` function. It does change the file extension and the type stored in the db. If I upload an animated GIF for example, it is not actually converted and will still behave like a GIF – even if it's file extension is changed to PNG. What is the purpose of doing something like this? File types and extensions should be preserved, or the file should be fully converted, right?

Comment: Well nice question @kai, Sometimes you also need to change a file's metadata before it is saved to a particular store. For example, you might have a transformWrite function that changes the file type, so you need a beforeWrite function that changes the extension and content type to match. **from FSCollection Readme**

Comment: It would be nice to mark this answer as "accepted" if it helped you to also help other users with the same problem, or at least "up vote", I just realized that this is the second time I helped you and any of the 2 brands as "accepted" or "up vote" is a pleasure to help but it would be good to know if indeed I am helping or just confuse you more

Comment: So I'm stuck (again) as `gm` in `transformWrite` does only process JPGs – PNGs get corrupted (zero bytes). I think it's not the code but something is wrong with GraphicsMagick on my machine. Will try to get Imagemagick to work.

Comment: If you need help i work on home, so im full time on the pc, i can help you to accomplish whatever you are trying to do, just mail me ethan.rosanoo

Comment: Removing GraphicsMagick from my Mac worked (it seems to have problems with libpng on OSX). GM is now using Imagemagick instead. Anyway, thanks again to @Ethaan for taking the time to help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Even though Meteor is very good at keeping the client and server environments in sync, that doesn't mean it can do everything on the client that it can do on the server and vice versa. Converting images using ImageMagick would be one example of what you can *only do on the server*.

If I were to build something like this, I'd look into using [CollectionFS](https://atmospherejs.com/cfs/standard-packages) for syncing files. They also have [a section in the README](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#image-manipulation) that describes how to manipulate images before saving them, which seems to be just what you're after.